# Commutator of two elements in group algebra $\mathbb F_{5}D_{30}.$

Tags: group-theory, gap, nilpotent-groups

I want to understand how to find the commutator of two elements in the group algebra $\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30}$ using GAP. Additionally, I would like to determine the nilpotency class of the nilpotent group $1+J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30})$ which is a subgroup of unit group, where $J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30})$ represents the Jacobson radical of the group algebra $\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30}$. In this context, $D_{30}=\{{a,b\mid a^{15}=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}}\}$ denotes the dihedral group of order $30.$ Here, $\mathbb{F}_{5}$ is a field of characteristic $5$, consisting of $5$ elements.

It is already known that $({1+J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30})})^5=1$ since $(J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30}))^5=0$. The nilpotency class of $1+J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30})$ has been determined to be $4$ through calculations, but I would like to verify this using GAP.

How to demonstrate the nilpotency class of the nilpotent group $1+J(\mathbb{F}_{5}D_{30})$ as $4$, and to compute the commutator $(x,y)=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ where $x=a^3$ and $y=1+4b+a^9b$?

I only know how to define group algebra in GAP.

```
gap> LoadPackage("laguna");
true
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(30);;
gap> FG:=GroupRing(GF(5),G);
<algebra-with-one over GF(5), with 3 generators>
gap> IsGroupAlgebra(FG);
true
gap> RadicalOfAlgebra(FG);
<algebra of dimension 24 over GF(5)>
```

I am not familiar with GAP and would appreciate a thorough explanation of the example. If someone explains this example in detail, it will greatly assist me in applying the same methodology to any group algebra. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe this group has order 211758236813575084767080625169910490512847900390625, and GAP is unlikely to want to compute its nilpotecy class.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven and what about commutator of two elements?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven if it is possible to find commutators then also it will be very helpful to me .

Comment: By using commutators I will be able to find nilptency class.

Comment: One more thing we can reduce order by taking GF(5) instead of GF(5^3).

Comment: @Olexandr Konovalov How to reward that I don’t know know the process .

Comment: @neelkanth: see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty. I think it will remind me to award it after the bounty expires. Any any case, no actions from you needed right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done reasonably easily in the matrix world.

Start with the regular permutation representation:

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(30);;
gap> rep:=RegularActionHomomorphism(G);;
gap> H:=Image(rep,G);
Group([ (1,2)(3,30)(4,24)(5,29)(6,21)(7,28)(8,27)(9,18)(10,26)(11,25)(12,15)
  (13,23)(14,22)(16,20)(17,19), (1,3,7,4,8,13,9,14,19,15,20,25,21,26,29)
  (2,5,10,6,11,16,12,17,22,18,23,27,24,28,30), (1,4,9,15,21)(2,6,12,18,24)
  (3,8,14,20,26)(5,11,17,23,28)(7,13,19,25,29)(10,16,22,27,30) ])
```

Then form matrices and the algebra generated by them:

```
gap> mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(H),x->PermutationMat(x,30,GF(5)));
gap> A:=Algebra(GF(5),mats);
<algebra over GF(5), with 3 generators>
gap> R:=RadicalOfAlgebra(A);
<algebra of dimension 24 over GF(5)>
```

Form a group from a basis of the radical

```
gap> gens:=List(Basis(R),x->x+One(A));;
gap> B:=Group(gens);
<matrix group with 24 generators>
```

You could calculate commutators in this matrix representation. But GAP can do more.

Now we use the `recog` package. Slight caveats: 1) This has a number of dependencies, and might not be entirely trivial to install. 2) It still lacks verificationm, and so we need to check that the resulting group order is correct:

```
gap> LoadPackage("Recog");
true
gap> Size(RecognizeGroup(B));
59604644775390625
gap> 5^24;
59604644775390625
```

Since the group must be solvable, we now can use my `matgrp` package to convert to a pc presentation:

```
gap> LoadPackage("matgrp");
true
gap> ff:=FittingFreeLiftSetup(B);;
gap> pc:=Image(ff.pcisom);
<pc group of size 59604644775390625 with 24 generators>
```

and get a pc presented version of the group. (Again, check that the order is correct!)
In this represenation we can easily calculate the nilpotency class:

```
gap> NilpotencyClassOfGroup(pc);
4
```

You can compute the commutator of certain elements through the matrices. Say, you want to compute the commutator of $1+f_2+f_2f_3$ with $1+f_1f_2^2-f_1f_2^2f_3^4$, you would compute a basis of the algebra, corresponding to elements:

```
gap> elms:=Elements(G);
[ <identity> of ..., f1, f2, f3, f1*f2, f1*f3, f2^2, f2*f3, f3^2, f1*f2^2,
  f1*f2*f3, f1*f3^2, f2^2*f3, f2*f3^2, f3^3, f1*f2^2*f3, f1*f2*f3^2, f1*f3^3,
  f2^2*f3^2, f2*f3^3, f3^4, f1*f2^2*f3^2, f1*f2*f3^3, f1*f3^4, f2^2*f3^3,
  f2*f3^4, f1*f2^2*f3^3, f1*f2*f3^4, f2^2*f3^4, f1*f2^2*f3^4 ]
gap> bas:=List(elms,x->PermutationMat(ImagesRepresentative(rep,x),30,GF(5)));;
gap> bas:=Basis(A,bas);;
```

Then find the matrices for $c$ and $d$ in there and form the two elements:

```
gap> f1mat:=bas[Position(elms,G.1)];;
gap> f2mat:=bas[Position(elms,G.2)];;
gap> f3mat:=bas[Position(elms,G.3)];;
gap> elm1:=f1mat^0+f2mat+f2mat*f3mat;;
gap> elm2:=f1mat^0+f1mat*f2mat^2-f1mat*f2mat^2*f3mat^4;;
```

Then compute coefficients of the commutator:

```
gap> co:=List(Coefficients(bas,Comm(elm1,elm2)),Int);
[ 0, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3 ]
gap> sel:=Filtered([1..Length(elms)],x->co[x]<>0);
[ 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29,
  30 ]
gap> List(sel,x->[co[x],elms[x]]);
[ [ 2, f1 ], [ 4, f2 ], [ 4, f1*f2 ], [ 2, f2^2 ], [ 4, f2*f3 ], [ 3, f3^2 ],
  [ 2, f1*f2^2 ], [ 2, f1*f2*f3 ], [ 3, f1*f3^2 ], [ 3, f2*f3^2 ],
  [ 3, f3^3 ], [ 2, f1*f2^2*f3 ], [ 3, f1*f2*f3^2 ], [ 2, f2^2*f3^2 ],
  [ 1, f2*f3^3 ], [ 1, f1*f2*f3^3 ], [ 3, f2^2*f3^3 ], [ 3, f2*f3^4 ],
  [ 3, f1*f2^2*f3^3 ], [ 3, f2^2*f3^4 ], [ 3, f1*f2^2*f3^4 ] ]
```

and you see that it starts with $2f_1+4f_2+4f_1f_2+\cdots$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much sir . Sir is there any way to find commutator of $x$ and $y$, where $x=a^3$ and $y=1+4b+a^9b?$

Comment: if I got an answer to this then It will solve my whole problem. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Yes. You take the images of $x$ and $y$ in the matrix representation and compute their commutator. Then decompose in the basis for $A$ to see how to represent the element.

Comment: sir if you add this also in answer then I will be very thankful to you. As I am not having knowledge in GAP.

Comment: Sir its working. Thank you .

Comment: can you tell me about commutator? How to find with example as above.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for solving my whole problem.

Comment: Sir is there any alternative of \begin{verbatim}ff:=FittingFreeLiftSetup(B);; \end{verbatim}? As my computer stop working for slightly large group. I tried it for $D(120).$

Comment: ff:=FittingFreeLiftSetup(B);; Alternatives